# Can I move my European WoW account to a US server?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a paid European WoW account, but would like to play with friends on a US server. [This site](http://petebarrwatson.com/2006/02/26/eu-us-world-of-warcraft-and-how-to-play-on-both/) claims that it's possible by editing a line in the realm list file, but that didn't work for me. Other sites claim that it's impossible. Is there a way to switch between EU and US servers with a single account?

Comment: i have the same problem with that , i buy all the game , and when i go install i make my account for US , and cant change anything of this , because i put all cd key's from disk to my US account , if some know any wway to change , please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to transfer an account to a different region. Sorry. :(

Editing your `realmlist.wtf` file as that link describes will make your game client **connect to** the US servers, but it doesn't change where your characters are **stored** or what **type of account** you have. The only reason you'd want to do that is if you had both a EU account *and* a US account, and wanted to switch between them without installing a second copy of WoW.

Answer (score 2):

No its not, and my guess is the replies on that blog are fake. Everything is partitioned in the different regions, for example EU & NA battle.net accoutns cannot chat with each other via realid and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

No, your account is tied to a region. The realmlist.wtf file is just for the purpose of getting the realms from a different region. So lets say you have created an US account, you would only have to change the realmlist.wtf file to change the login servers (and realm servers) to those from the US.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is possible. If you create a US account and buy a subscription for that account you can transfer your characters to that account and play over there. But the downside is that with this thr region transfer for your characters costs almost half the game did by itself and there is also a glitch with this where you can lose your armour and money. My friend had done this and notified me about the bug before i did the transfer myself. Although it only happened to him once.

Answer (score -2):

A guy I was seeing from Norway Switched his EU account to US account so he could play WoW with me.  He changed his realmlist.wtf file and he can play just fine.

His account now has him listed as paying via US currency, with access to US realms, battlenet store, etc.